# Select from multiple tables using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am trying to execute the following SQL statement using linq:

```
SELECT TTT.SomeField
FROM Table1 as T, Table2 as TT, Table3 as TTT
WHERE (T.NumberID = 100 OR T.NumberID = 101)
  AND T.QuestionID = 200
  AND T.ResponseID = TT.ResponseID
  AND TT.AnswerID = TTT.AnswerID
```

Essentially getting one field from a third table based on primary/foreign key relationships to the other 2 tables. It is expected to have a single result every time.

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/join

Comment: Can you post examples of the 3 tables and the result you want out?

Answer (score 2):

```
var query = from t in db.Table1
            join tt in db.Table2 on t.ResponseID equals tt.ResponseID
            join ttt in db.Table3 on tt.AnswerID equals ttt.AnswerID
            where (t.NumberID == 100 || t.NumberID == 101) && t.QuestionID == 200
            select ttt.SomeField
```

If you always expect single result, you can wrap this in `().Single()`, or, if there might be no results found, in `().SingleOrDefault()`.

Comment: sure thing! also I think he wants TTT.somefield. Not to be 'that guy'

Answer (score 0):

*If I understand you correct.* You should read something about `Joins` I guess.
[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb311040.aspx)